# FPGA outputs are always high with basic and/or program

Tags: fpga, verilog, intel-fpga, quartus-ii, cyclone

So I am just getting started developing with an [Altera Cyclone II EP265 mini board](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LEMKR92), and I am having some trouble getting a program that outputs the "and" and "or" of three inputs working.

The full Quartus II project is located [here.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ul3t8gm6gcyf7vq/BasicLogic.zip)

And here is the verilog code I'm using:

```
module Logic
    (
        //Inputs
        in_1,
        in_2,
        in_3,
        //Outputs
        out_1,
        out_2
    );

//Port definitions
input in_1;
input   in_2;
input   in_3;

output out_1;
output out_2;

assign out_1 = in_1 & in_2 & in_3;
assign out_2 = in_1 | in_2 | in_3;

endmodule
```

When I upload this to the board, the three onboard LEDs are always set to high, as well as the two output pins I specified in the pin planner. I tried moving the outputs to one of the unspecified pins, and this output was low.

The steps I am doing to upload this are: Open Quartus II > Tools > Programmer > Connect USB blaster > Specify blaster in hardware settings > Run.

Can anyone see why this is not working correctly?

EDIT: Compilation messages:

```
Info: *******************************************************************
Info: Running Quartus II 64-Bit Analysis & Synthesis
    Info: Version 13.0.1 Build 232 06/12/2013 Service Pack 1 SJ Web Edition
    Info: Processing started: Fri Aug 15 15:09:30 2014
Info: Command: quartus_map --read_settings_files=on --write_settings_files=off BasicLogic -c BasicLogic
Warning (20028): Parallel compilation is not licensed and has been disabled
Info (12021): Found 1 design units, including 1 entities, in source file logic.v
    Info (12023): Found entity 1: Logic
Info (12021): Found 1 design units, including 1 entities, in source file BasicLogic.bdf
    Info (12023): Found entity 1: BasicLogic
Info (12127): Elaborating entity "BasicLogic" for the top level hierarchy
Info (12128): Elaborating entity "Logic" for hierarchy "Logic:inst"
Info (16010): Generating hard_block partition "hard_block:auto_generated_inst"
    Info (16011): Adding 0 node(s), including 0 DDIO, 0 PLL, 0 transceiver and 0 LCELL
Info (21057): Implemented 7 device resources after synthesis - the final resource count might be different
    Info (21058): Implemented 3 input pins
    Info (21059): Implemented 2 output pins
    Info (21061): Implemented 2 logic cells
Info: Quartus II 64-Bit Analysis & Synthesis was successful. 0 errors, 1 warning
    Info: Peak virtual memory: 607 megabytes
    Info: Processing ended: Fri Aug 15 15:09:32 2014
    Info: Elapsed time: 00:00:02
    Info: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:01
Info: *******************************************************************
Info: Running Quartus II 64-Bit Fitter
    Info: Version 13.0.1 Build 232 06/12/2013 Service Pack 1 SJ Web Edition
    Info: Processing started: Fri Aug 15 15:09:33 2014
Info: Command: quartus_fit --read_settings_files=off --write_settings_files=off BasicLogic -c BasicLogic
Info: qfit2_default_script.tcl version: #1
Info: Project  = BasicLogic
Info: Revision = BasicLogic
Warning (20028): Parallel compilation is not licensed and has been disabled
Info (119006): Selected device EP2C5T144C8 for design "BasicLogic"
Info (21077): Low junction temperature is 0 degrees C
Info (21077): High junction temperature is 85 degrees C
Info (171003): Fitter is performing an Auto Fit compilation, which may decrease Fitter effort to reduce compilation time
Warning (292013): Feature LogicLock is only available with a valid subscription license. You can purchase a software subscription to gain full access to this feature.
Info (176444): Device migration not selected. If you intend to use device migration later, you may need to change the pin assignments as they may be incompatible with other devices
    Info (176445): Device EP2C5T144I8 is compatible
    Info (176445): Device EP2C8T144C8 is compatible
    Info (176445): Device EP2C8T144I8 is compatible
Info (169124): Fitter converted 3 user pins into dedicated programming pins
    Info (169125): Pin ~ASDO~ is reserved at location 1
    Info (169125): Pin ~nCSO~ is reserved at location 2
    Info (169125): Pin ~LVDS41p/nCEO~ is reserved at location 76
Critical Warning (332012): Synopsys Design Constraints File file not found: 'BasicLogic.sdc'. A Synopsys Design Constraints File is required by the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer to get proper timing constraints. Without it, the Compiler will not properly optimize the design.
Info (332144): No user constrained base clocks found in the design
Info (332096): The command derive_clocks did not find any clocks to derive.  No clocks were created or changed.
Warning (332068): No clocks defined in design.
Info (332130): Timing requirements not specified -- quality metrics such as performance may be sacrificed to reduce compilation time.
Info (176233): Starting register packing
Info (176235): Finished register packing
    Extra Info (176219): No registers were packed into other blocks
Info (171121): Fitter preparation operations ending: elapsed time is 00:00:00
Info (170189): Fitter placement preparation operations beginning
Info (170190): Fitter placement preparation operations ending: elapsed time is 00:00:00
Info (170191): Fitter placement operations beginning
Info (170137): Fitter placement was successful
Info (170192): Fitter placement operations ending: elapsed time is 00:00:00
Info (170193): Fitter routing operations beginning
Info (170195): Router estimated average interconnect usage is 0% of the available device resources
    Info (170196): Router estimated peak interconnect usage is 0% of the available device resources in the region that extends from location X0_Y0 to location X13_Y14
Info (170194): Fitter routing operations ending: elapsed time is 00:00:00
Info (170199): The Fitter performed an Auto Fit compilation.  Optimizations were skipped to reduce compilation time.
    Info (170201): Optimizations that may affect the design's routability were skipped
    Info (170200): Optimizations that may affect the design's timing were skipped
Info (11888): Total time spent on timing analysis during the Fitter is 0.16 seconds.
Info (306004): Started post-fitting delay annotation
Warning (306006): Found 2 output pins without output pin load capacitance assignment
    Info (306007): Pin "4" has no specified output pin load capacitance -- assuming default load capacitance of 0 pF for timing analysis
    Info (306007): Pin "5" has no specified output pin load capacitance -- assuming default load capacitance of 0 pF for timing analysis
Info (306005): Delay annotation completed successfully
Info (306004): Started post-fitting delay annotation
Info (306005): Delay annotation completed successfully
Info (11218): Fitter post-fit operations ending: elapsed time is 00:00:00
Warning (169174): The Reserve All Unused Pins setting has not been specified, and will default to 'As output driving ground'.
Info (144001): Generated suppressed messages file /media/alex/Data/Verilog/BasicLogic/output_files/BasicLogic.fit.smsg
Info: Quartus II 64-Bit Fitter was successful. 0 errors, 6 warnings
    Info: Peak virtual memory: 639 megabytes
    Info: Processing ended: Fri Aug 15 15:09:36 2014
    Info: Elapsed time: 00:00:03
    Info: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:02
Info: *******************************************************************
Info: Running Quartus II 64-Bit Assembler
    Info: Version 13.0.1 Build 232 06/12/2013 Service Pack 1 SJ Web Edition
    Info: Processing started: Fri Aug 15 15:09:38 2014
Info: Command: quartus_asm --read_settings_files=off --write_settings_files=off BasicLogic -c BasicLogic
Info (115031): Writing out detailed assembly data for power analysis
Info (115030): Assembler is generating device programming files
Info: Quartus II 64-Bit Assembler was successful. 0 errors, 0 warnings
    Info: Peak virtual memory: 541 megabytes
    Info: Processing ended: Fri Aug 15 15:09:39 2014
    Info: Elapsed time: 00:00:01
    Info: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:01
Info (293026): Skipped module PowerPlay Power Analyzer due to the assignment FLOW_ENABLE_POWER_ANALYZER
Info: *******************************************************************
Info: Running Quartus II 64-Bit TimeQuest Timing Analyzer
    Info: Version 13.0.1 Build 232 06/12/2013 Service Pack 1 SJ Web Edition
    Info: Processing started: Fri Aug 15 15:09:41 2014
Info: Command: quartus_sta BasicLogic -c BasicLogic
Info: qsta_default_script.tcl version: #1
Warning (20028): Parallel compilation is not licensed and has been disabled
Info (21077): Low junction temperature is 0 degrees C
Info (21077): High junction temperature is 85 degrees C
Critical Warning (332012): Synopsys Design Constraints File file not found: 'BasicLogic.sdc'. A Synopsys Design Constraints File is required by the TimeQuest Timing Analyzer to get proper timing constraints. Without it, the Compiler will not properly optimize the design.
Info (332142): No user constrained base clocks found in the design. Calling "derive_clocks -period 1.0"
Info (332096): The command derive_clocks did not find any clocks to derive.  No clocks were created or changed.
Warning (332068): No clocks defined in design.
Info: Found TIMEQUEST_REPORT_SCRIPT_INCLUDE_DEFAULT_ANALYSIS = ON
Info (332159): No clocks to report
Info: Analyzing Slow Model
Info (332140): No fmax paths to report
Info (332140): No Setup paths to report
Info (332140): No Hold paths to report
Info (332140): No Recovery paths to report
Info (332140): No Removal paths to report
Info (332140): No Minimum Pulse Width paths to report
Info (332001): The selected device family is not supported by the report_metastability command.
Info: Analyzing Fast Model
Info (332142): No user constrained base clocks found in the design. Calling "derive_clocks -period 1.0"
Info (332096): The command derive_clocks did not find any clocks to derive.  No clocks were created or changed.
Warning (332068): No clocks defined in design.
Info (332140): No Setup paths to report
Info (332140): No Hold paths to report
Info (332140): No Recovery paths to report
Info (332140): No Removal paths to report
Info (332140): No Minimum Pulse Width paths to report
Info (332001): The selected device family is not supported by the report_metastability command.
Info (332102): Design is not fully constrained for setup requirements
Info (332102): Design is not fully constrained for hold requirements
Info: Quartus II 64-Bit TimeQuest Timing Analyzer was successful. 0 errors, 4 warnings
    Info: Peak virtual memory: 497 megabytes
    Info: Processing ended: Fri Aug 15 15:09:42 2014
    Info: Elapsed time: 00:00:01
    Info: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:01
Info: *******************************************************************
Info: Running Quartus II 64-Bit EDA Netlist Writer
    Info: Version 13.0.1 Build 232 06/12/2013 Service Pack 1 SJ Web Edition
    Info: Processing started: Fri Aug 15 15:09:44 2014
Info: Command: quartus_eda --read_settings_files=off --write_settings_files=off BasicLogic -c BasicLogic
Info (204026): Generated files "BasicLogic.vo", "BasicLogic_fast.vo", "BasicLogic_v.sdo" and "BasicLogic_v_fast.sdo" in directory "/media/alex/Data/Verilog/BasicLogic/simulation/modelsim/" for EDA simulation tool
Info: Quartus II 64-Bit EDA Netlist Writer was successful. 0 errors, 0 warnings
    Info: Peak virtual memory: 799 megabytes
    Info: Processing ended: Fri Aug 15 15:09:45 2014
    Info: Elapsed time: 00:00:01
    Info: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:01
Info (293000): Quartus II Full Compilation was successful. 0 errors, 11 warnings
```

EDIT 2: Report after analysis and elaboration (some possible solutions here):

```
Info: *******************************************************************
Info: Running Quartus II 64-Bit Analysis & Elaboration
    Info: Version 13.0.1 Build 232 06/12/2013 Service Pack 1 SJ Web Edition
    Info: Processing started: Mon Aug 18 08:30:16 2014
Info: Command: quartus_map --read_settings_files=on --write_settings_files=off BasicLogic -c BasicLogic --analysis_and_elaboration
Warning (20028): Parallel compilation is not licensed and has been disabled
Info (12021): Found 1 design units, including 1 entities, in source file logic.v
    Info (12023): Found entity 1: Logic
Warning (12019): Can't analyze file -- file BasicLogic.v is missing
Warning (12125): Using design file BasicLogic.bdf, which is not specified as a design file for the current project, but contains definitions for 1 design units and 1 entities in project
    Info (12023): Found entity 1: BasicLogic
Info (12127): Elaborating entity "BasicLogic" for the top level hierarchy
Info (12128): Elaborating entity "Logic" for hierarchy "Logic:inst"
Info: Quartus II 64-Bit Analysis & Elaboration was successful. 0 errors, 3 warnings
    Info: Peak virtual memory: 867 megabytes
    Info: Processing ended: Mon Aug 18 08:30:17 2014
    Info: Elapsed time: 00:00:01
    Info: Total CPU time (on all processors): 00:00:01
```

Comment: Can you post the synthesizer/fitter messages?

Comment: Are these the compilation messages or are they from a different part of the process?

Comment: that's not called compilation, but that's what I am asking.

Comment: Added the messages.

Comment: Well it all looks good to me, might it be a problem of the programmer? Also, have you loaded the proper pin assignment file?

Comment: I used the Quartus II pin planner, not sure if there's anything else in particular I need to do.

Comment: that should be enough. Have you got some example projects that work on that board? maybe you can try and modify them and see if this works (it should). There are quite a lot of things that is easy to miss behind a keyboard... Are you doing this on your own? Maybe your teacher or a more experienced friend/coworker can help you.

Comment: I can try some other projects (no examples are given for this board), but I can try examples others have written such as the 3-bit binary counter. In the meantime, some more details: I tried changing the output pins to the built-in LEDs, but for some reason, the originally assigned ones are still the ones used. I also tried briefly connecting an output pin to an input and both lights went out during that time (probably a short and the inputs are working correctly). This project is on my own.

Comment: So the problem lies in the pin assignment thing. I am sorry there really is so many things that can be wrong... I'm still thinking of the pin assignment file. What programmer are you using? Trying other working projects should be the next step imo.

Comment: I also discovered some additional warnings today after running analysis and elaboration... could the issue be within the "BasicLogic.v is missing" message?

Answer (score 1):

Since this is your first FPGA project with this board, there are several things that could be going wrong. (I go through this kind of thing myself with every new development system)

Maybe the board isn't powered -- the Amazon link doesn't say whether this board includes the required 5V DC power supply. If this is anything like the ones on ebay, the board should come already loaded with some code that lights up the LEDs. Normally an FPGA board vendor loads a test program onto the board to prove there are no assembly errors, before they ship the board. So when it is first powered up, I'd expect to see an LED light up.

Maybe the JTAG programmer was connected to the wrong header -- this board has two different 2x5 shrouded headers, one for JTAG loading and the other for SPI platform flash loading.

Maybe the design is actually working? How are you testing it? I know that EP2C5T144 board doesn't have much on/board switches and LEDs. The input and output pins are on dual-row headers. It's easy to mis-count or get the inner row / outer row connection swapped. I looked through your project report files and don't see anything wrong. To test this code, you'd have to connect some wires to your in_1, in_2, in_3 and connect each to either 3.3V or GND. Then go through the "truth table" combinations, and observe the output.

Your example HDL code was correctly translated, based on this part of the log file:

```
Info (21057): Implemented 7 device resources after synthesis - the final resource count might be different
    Info (21058): Implemented 3 input pins
    Info (21059): Implemented 2 output pins
    Info (21061): Implemented 2 logic cells
```

This is exactly the resource usage I'd expect for a pair of three-input gates. I also checked through the other reports to see if any of the logic got removed by later stages, but it looks to me like it got through place/route/map and should have ended up in the final configuration bitstream.

On a side note: it's good practice to use net names like "in_1", "out_1" like you used in logic.v, instead of just "1" - "5". Makes it easier to understand what's intended. The pinout report (BasicLogic.pin) would be easier to read if the toplevel net names matched up with your HDL code.

```
Pin Name/Usage               : Location  : Dir.   : I/O Standard      : Voltage : I/O Bank  : User Assignment
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1                            : 40        : input  : 3.3-V LVTTL       :         : 4         : Y              
2                            : 41        : input  : 3.3-V LVTTL       :         : 4         : Y              
3                            : 42        : input  : 3.3-V LVTTL       :         : 4         : Y              
4                            : 71        : output : 3.3-V LVTTL       :         : 4         : Y              
5                            : 72        : output : 3.3-V LVTTL       :         : 4         : Y
```

Suggestion: try an LED blinker project next. Just use a 24-bit counter (clocked by the on-board 50MHz system clock) and the MSB of that counter should blink slow enough you can see it blink, but fast enough you know it's doing something. I've learned the hard way to always include an LED blinker diagnostic on my projects, so I can confirm that the FPGA actually got programmed with valid code.

Comment: I also discovered some additional warnings today after running analysis and elaboration... could the issue be within the "BasicLogic.v is missing" message?

Comment: The 'basiclogic.v missing' message may be because you've used a schematic as your toplevel module. I normally use a verilog module as my toplevel (VHDL would also work). The only difference with the toplevel module is that the module's input and output ports map to actual pin, instead of internal nodes. As Vladimir Cravero points out, you need to connect toplevel port names to physical device pins.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that the problem is with pull up resiters .you need them to pull down. These outputs are reverse logic

Comment: Where did the OP say they have pull up resistors?